multi-file add-on cannot find import
I am working toward have a multi-file add-on, as our add-on is getting pretty long. I'm starting with a trivial example to build up from and can't even get that to work.
I have two files at top level in my project, simple_addon.py and simple_panel.py, borrowed from the Blender Scripting Tutorial.  If I put the panel contents into the simple_addon.py file, all works. But when I separate it out, Blender cannot find it to import.
I've tried
import simple_panel
  File "/Users/ron/Library/Application Support/Blender/4.0/scripts/addons/simple_addon.py", line 1, in <module>
    import simple_panel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_panel'

from simple_panel import SimplePanel
  File "/Users/ron/Library/Application Support/Blender/4.0/scripts/addons/simple_addon.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simple_panel import SimplePanel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_panel'

I tried adding an __init__.py and using that as the addon, which doesn't load anything.
I tried
from .simple_panel import SimplePanel
  File "/Users/ron/Library/Application Support/Blender/4.0/scripts/addons/simple_addon.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .simple_panel import SimplePanel
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I'm sure that from a working example with two files, I could grow my solution. Can anyone show me an example that will work? Ideally, it would allow subfolders but I can either live without those or work it out from a simpler working case.

The existing add-ons all have an __init__.py that says, for example: from . import foo, but when I create an init like that, Blender doesn't even add anything. Still confused. A working example that can be added as an add-on, with a couple of separate files, would be great. BTW, Blender 4.0 and MacOS. Thanks!

i created an addon template with some simple automatic config https://github.com/hkunz/blender-addon-template read the README.md for more info. let me know where u find problems.


create a folder

put your working (!) add-on with the name ´__init__.py´ in it

add another .py file with additional code (let's name it "another.py" as example

add this to your ´__init__.py´ file:  "from .another import *"

now you can call/use whatever you defined in another.py in ´__init__.py´

right click on your folder of 1) -> compress

-> now you got a zip file, which you can install as add-on


Hint: in Blender 4.2 use install legacy add-on (don't know whether that's in 4.0 the same, else just install "normal")

Thank you! I didn't know that I had to zip the files, but that, plus your other instructions, has me on the right track I think. To get the __init__.py to have the underbars, use a single back tick on each side of the string. And in English, the Menu item is "compress". Thank you kindly! I think I'm on the way!

I am going to assume that I need to do the reload / optional import trick that is shown in the various examples and add-ons that ship with Blender. Is that necessary, a good idea, or too much? I am sure that we'll be updating this add-on from time to time, so either we'll have to delete it manually or do the reload?

@JanetRossini: thank you, i updated my answer. tbh i would recommend using VSC to write you add-on. There is an add-on from Jacques Lucke for VSC with which you can automatically reload your add-on without opening + closing Blender. Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=q06-hER7Y1Q
